# HTML Agility to extract PHP tags

Tags: c#, php, html-agility-pack

What syntax should be used with HTML Agility Pack to extract all

Tags from a Php file..?

```
HtmlNodeCollection tags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//??php");
```

Throws an exception (invalid token).

Tried escaping ? with ?? and \?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Agility Pack does choke on nodes with `?` in the name. The simplest option is probably to go through the HTML string before you load it into a document object and replace instances of `<?` with `<php` and so-on. That doesn't handle any nasty cases like having a string literal on the page with "&lt?" but really, how often does that happen?

Comment: Pity.. It chokes on ?..

Replaced with token as suggested.

Thanks